# Units of area parameter in ngspice

Tags: spice, simulation

Can anyone tell me what are the units of area parameter used in ngspice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of "area" can depend upon the device.  For diodes it is the physical area, for MOSFets it can also be M or the scaling factor.  This is because in MOSfets the L and W can be used to calculate the drain and source areas (or you can give AS and AD in square meters directly - Si units), so M is used to scale for # of parallel devices when areas are not given directly.

Comment: I am asking in what units do we actually specify the area i.e. whether in meter-square or centimeter-square

Comment: Read the answer, it's  in there